# How do I download json file from remote saver and save to bundle for offline access

Tags: json, swift, local, getjson

I am able to download a json file from a server and put it into a TableView each time the App is opened. (see code below)

However, I also want to allow offline access using the last file downloaded. So essentially I am having trouble working out how to save the downloaded file for local access offline. Any help (especially examples) much appreciated.

```
 class KalkanTableController: UITableViewController {

var TableData:Array< String > = Array < String >()


override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()


get_data_from_url("http://ftp.MY FILE LOCATION/kalkanInfoTest.json")
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "kalkanInfoTest", ofType: "json") {
        do {
            let jsonData = try NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options: NSData.ReadingOptions.mappedIfSafe)
            do {
                let jsonResult: NSDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData as Data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
            } catch {}
        } catch {}
    }
}


override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return TableData.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = TableData[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

func get_data_from_url(_ link:String)
{
    let url:URL = URL(string: link)!
    let session = URLSession.shared

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.cachePolicy = URLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData


    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {
        (
        data, response, error) in

        guard let _:Data = data, let _:URLResponse = response  , error == nil else {

           return
        }
        self.extract_json(data!)
    }) 
    task.resume()
}


func extract_json(_ data: Data)
{
    let json: Any?
    do
    {
        json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
    }
    catch
    {
        return
    }

    guard let data_list = json as? NSArray else
    {
        return
    }

    if let item_list = json as? NSArray
    {
        for i in 0 ..< data_list.count
        {
            if let item_obj = item_list[i] as? NSDictionary
            {
                if let item_name = item_obj["kalkanInfo"] as? Stri                          
                    {
                         TableData.append(item_name)

                         print(item_name)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {self.do_table_refresh()})
}

func do_table_refresh()
{
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        return
    })
}
```

}

Comment: I'm not sure about your problem here... but you can read more about __[data  storing on iOS](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/index.html)__.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to save your json locally using these methods to save on disk

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if readKalkanDataFromDisk() {
        extract_json(readKalkanDataFromDisk())
    } else {
        get_data_from_url("http://ftp.MY FILE LOCATION/kalkanInfoTest.json")
    }
}

func get_data_from_url(_ link:String)
{
    let url:URL = URL(string: link)!
    let session = URLSession.shared

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.cachePolicy = URLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData


    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {
        (
        data, response, error) in

        guard let _:Data = data, let _:URLResponse = response  , error == nil else {

            return
        }
        saveKalkanDataOnDisk(kalkanData: data!)
        self.extract_json(data!)
    }) 
    task.resume()
}

func saveKalkanDataOnDisk(kalkanData: Data) {
    do {
        let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        let fileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("Kalkan.json")
        try kalkanData.write(to: fileURL, options: .atomic)
    } catch { }
}

func readKalkanDataFromDisk() -> Data? {
    let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let filePath = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("Kalkan.json").path
    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: filePath), let data = FileManager.default.contents(atPath: filePath) {
        return data
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Hi Ramon. Thank you for taking the time to post. I am not sure exactly how I would call the functions or where I would call them from? Can you illuminate for me? best wishes

Comment: You can call saveData inside your task completion handler after you get your json from the url and call readData on viewDidLoad to see if you have any data on disk or if you have to download it from the web.

Comment: @RamonVasconceolos

Sorry, I am being thick. Can you show me?

Comment: @rRamon Vasconcelos

Thanks Ramon. I am busy the rest of the day but will have another go at implementing it tomorrow morning :-)